# PyQt: How convert my script to GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbXez-lixP0) for a PyQt5 GUI window:

Here's My code on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qV9Zz7aV).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


def window1():
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
b = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Comparison Report', w)
l1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(w)
l2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(w)
l1.setText('Main Page')
b.setGeometry(200, 100, 300, 70)
w.setWindowTitle('Diff Util')
w.setGeometry(800, 200, 720, 800)
l1.move(310, 5)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

#import file_report

#def on_click(self):
#file_report()


window1()
```

Here's a comparison file script also on pastebin... but i Need 10rep to link it >_>

```
import sys
import os
import difflib

first_file = input("Select original file: ")
second_file = input("Select second file for comparison: ")

first_file_lines = open(first_file).readlines()
second_file_lines = open(second_file).readlines()

difference = difflib.HtmlDiff(tabsize=8, 
wrapcolumn=100).make_file(first_file_lines, second_file_lines, first_file, second_file, charset='utf-8')
difference_report = open('difference_report.html', 'w')
difference_report.write(difference)
difference_report.close()

os.startfile('difference_report.html')
```

My question is, how to connect my file_report.py to the pushbutton I've created with PyQt5?

As you can see I commented out "import file_report" because from my understanding I'm supposed to import my script... but the import causes it to run the script in terminal, and after execution will open my GUI. I would like to run this script, but contain it within the GUI window I've created instead of opening a terminal for execution.

So where in the PyQt5 script should I import, and include the .py file?

Comment: input() is a blocking task so it is not recommended to use it in a GUI, the GUI you have as components that replace that task, in the case of PyQt is the QLineEdit.

Comment: Alright, so I would have to change the input() method to something PyQt5 could interpret for its own user input? So this means I would have to rewrite my script to include PyQt5 elements?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want from you.

Comment: I have no insight on this but im just now learning what QT is and I feel like they really missed an opportunity not calling the python library for it QtPy

Comment: I could help you but I have a problem, I do not understand startfile (), Linux does not exist but if you tell me what you do you could give an example

Comment: @zero01alpha what is QtPy?

Comment: @eyllansec say it out loud and it sounds like "cutie pie". It's something "nice/sweet" you would say to someone you like.

Comment: @eyllanesc Just a play on words, Cutie Pie is a term of endearment

Comment: @eyllanesc: I'm having issues with the import for my re-write: " from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QInputDialog, QLineEdit" gives me an error saying it can't import this stuff :(

Comment: @grassytrainer I have placed an example of how to replace elements that are not user friendly with the GUI. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUIs are not friendly with blocking tasks since for their existence they create a loop. Therefore the function input() should not be used, the solution to use elements provided by the library as QLineEdit, PyQt also provides dialog boxes for the selection of files.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import difflib

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QGridLayout())

        self.le1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("", self)
        self.le2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("", self)
        self.le3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("", self)
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select first file")
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select second file")
        self.btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select save File")
        self.btnRun = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Run")

        self.layout().addWidget(self.le1, 1, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.le2, 2, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.le3, 3, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.btn1, 1, 2)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.btn2, 2, 2)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.btn3, 3, 2)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.btnRun, 4, 2)
        self.btnRun.clicked.connect(self.onRun)

        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.selectFirstFile)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.selectSecondFile)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.selectSaveFile)

    def selectFirstFile(self):
        filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Files", QtCore.QDir.currentPath(), "*.html")
        if filename != "":
            self.le1.setText(filename)

    def selectSecondFile(self):
        filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Files", QtCore.QDir.currentPath(), "*.html")
        if filename != "":
            self.le2.setText(filename)

    def selectSaveFile(self):
        filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Select Files", QtCore.QDir.currentPath(), "*.html")
        if filename != "":
            self.le3.setText(filename)


    def onRun(self):
        first_file = self.le1.text()
        second_file = self.le2.text()
        output_file = self.le3.text()

        first_file_lines = open(first_file).readlines()
        second_file_lines = open(second_file).readlines()

        difference = difflib.HtmlDiff(tabsize=8, wrapcolumn=100).make_file(first_file_lines, second_file_lines, first_file, second_file, charset='utf-8')
        difference_report = open(output_file, 'w')
        difference_report.write(difference)
        difference_report.close()
        QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(output_file))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do, but what I don't understand is how PyQt5 wants it written. Each time I see how to `import` it's written differently. Then I end up getting mixed results as I try to write things out. Then somewhere in my code pylint claims "you haven't defined this variable even though you wrote it up above." :[ Thanks for the answer, but I'm tearing out my hair trying to understand it all.

Comment: there are many ways to import in python, for example to use QLineEdit you can in the following ways: `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()`

or this other way:

`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit

le = QLineEdit()`

Comment: Another thing, the dynamics of a GUI is different from the programming that we will call initial. In the case of yours the way to see your code is sequential from top to bottom, in the gui also happens the same but it is hidden. In the GUI you must perform a task before an event, this can be a click, modify the size of the GUI, etc. then the GUI warns us about those changes, in the case of PyQt does it through the signals and events, in the case of the signals we must connect it to some slot, that is to say that the application will call the slot when it notifies the signal.